# How To select last inserted Row in PHP , Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to create ID like **"A1 , A2, A3 .. etc**
So i tried like this

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT merge_id FROM merge_info ORDER BY merge_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
$s = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$merge_id5 = $s['merge_id'];
$count2=mysql_num_rows($q);
if($count2>0)
{
    $merge_id5 = explode("A",$merge_id5);   
    $mergeid_no = $merge_id5[1]+1;  
    $merge_id6 = $mergeid_no;
}
else
{
    $merge_id6 ="1";
}
if($count<1)
{
    $merge_id = $merge_id5;
}
```

Everything is working fine... but after creating A9, it create A10 then again it creates A10 **not moving to A11 , A12 . etc.,**  i think if i write correct query to fetch last inserted row i'll fix this issue

Please someone help me

```
db table :

merge_id  |  name |
      A1  |  xxxx |
      A2  |  yyyy |
      A3  |  zzzz |
        ....
        ....
      A9  |   sds |
      A10 |  dsfs |
```

Comment: is the merged id always begin with A?

Comment: i think better if you add new field that is auto increment

Comment: @wrecklez yes the merge id should be like this and i dont have to add autoincrement id like 1,2,3,4,.etc :( without using auto increment i have to do this

Comment: try my posted solution, i know it is not the best solution but it will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

i know it is not the best solution to your problem, but this will help you.
and just get the first record because if i add `LIMIT 1` the output is wrong :(

```
SELECT * FROM merge_info ORDER BY LENGTH(merge_id) DESC
```

Comment: it returns A10 but after inserting A11 again it returns A10 not moving to next "A11'

Comment: @user3419304 try it now, just get the first record

Comment: @user3419304 just remove the limit, then get only the first record in your PHP atleast we found out what is the latest record :) hope it will help, if i got a new and a better solution i will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:-

```
SELECT MAX(merge_id) FROM merge_info;
```

Comment: it returns A9 , but i want A10

Comment: change explode to implode. This maght be your solution.

Comment: i think there is no need to change any part of coding..! after A9 the the A10 stores after A1 ( A1,A10,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9) so i need to order the table as 1,2,3,4..9,10 then select last row. i dont know how to do that, someone help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you use an auto_increment field, to get the last insert row with LAST_INSERT_ID(), otherwise you can't be sure if the last row, the one you have inserted.

So long. To order with your solution, use this.

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(merge_id,2) DESC
```

Comment: SELECT merge_id
FROM merge_info
ORDER BY SUBSTRING( merge_id, 2 )
LIMIT 1   this query returns A1

Comment: Use DESC for ORDER, ASC is default

Answer (score 0):

Better approach to your problem could be ,
use AUTO_INCREMENT field and while displaying append 'A' to it.

Now to solve this you can use below SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM `merge_info` ORDER BY SUBSTRING(merge_id,2) DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

should change you merge_id column into auto increment column,and the change your query into below mentioned,

```
SELECT MAX(merge_id) FROM merge_info;
```

if you want id like A1,A2,A3 ... then you can use the below code for get it

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT merge_id FROM merge_info ORDER BY merge_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
                                         $s = mysql_fetch_array($q);
                                         $merge_id5 = $s['merge_id'];
                                         $count2=mysql_num_rows($q);

                    $merge_id="A".$merge_id5;
```

after above process,noe we have a meger_id like A1,A2.. on application side

Comment: Without autoincrement have to do this stuff !! if autoincrement has i do easily !!